# How to escape parentheses python

Tags: python, parentheses

I am the newbie in programming. The goal of this exercise is to convert a string to a new string where each character in the new string is "(" if that character appears only once in the original string, or ")" if that character appears more than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when determining if a character is a duplicate.

But when the code meet ) -- closing parentheses it generate wrong output. As I figured out, the problem is with regular expressions, but I didn't get how to fix code.

```
from collections import Counter

def duplicate_encode(word):
    counter = Counter(word.lower())
    counter2 = dict.copy(counter)

    print(counter2)

    for k,v in counter2.items():
        if counter2[k]==1:
            counter2[k]='('
        else:
            counter2[k]=')'
  
    for key in counter2.keys():
        word = str(word.lower()).replace(key, str(counter2[key])) 
    
    return word
```

For example:

`duplicate_encode('yy! R)!QvdG')` should return `)))((()((((` but I got `(((((((((((`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter


def duplicate_encode(word):
    res = list(word.lower())
    counter = Counter(word.lower())
    counter2 = dict.copy(counter)

    print(counter2)

    for k, value in enumerate(res):
        if counter2[value] == 1:
            res[k] = '('
        else:
            res[k] = ')'

    # for key in counter2.keys():
    #     word = str(word.lower()).replace(key, str(counter2[key]))

    return "".join(res)


res = duplicate_encode('yy! R)!QvdG')
print("res", res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when your input string contains a brace, like `(` or `)`.

When that happens, like it does in your example, the wrong characters get replaced, which you can verify by adding `print()` statements in your code, every time you change `word`.

I've replaced that part in your code.

```
from collections import Counter

def duplicate_encode(word):
    counter = Counter(word.lower())
    counter2 = dict.copy(counter)

    print(counter2)

    for k,v in counter2.items():
        if counter2[k]==1:
            counter2[k]='('
        else:
            counter2[k]=')'
    
    print(counter2)
    
    new_word = ''
    for character in word:
        new_word += counter2[character.lower()]
    
    return new_word
```

Note, however, that the code has quite a few redundancies and unnecessary usage of memory. It can be simplified to the following:

```
from collections import Counter

def duplicate_encode(word):
    lower_word = word.lower()
    new_word = ''
    counter = Counter(lower_word)
    
    for char in lower_word:
        if counter[char] > 1:
            new_word += ')'
        else:
            new_word += '('
    
    return new_word
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Start with a set of (unique) characters, loop over characters in the string, removing the character from that set, and if it is already removed then it must be a duplicate. Use this to build up a set of duplicated characters.

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word = word.upper()
    s = set(word)
    dups = set()

    for char in word:
        if char in s:
            s.remove(char)
        else:
            dups.add(char)

    return "".join(")" if char in dups else "("
                   for char in word)

print(duplicate_encode("'yy! R)!QvdG'"))
```

gives:

```
))))((()(((()
```

Comment: Doesn't this do the same thing in O(n^2) time (if char in dups for every char) which can easily be done in O(n) time? Unless I'm seeing things wrong, this is bad.

Comment: @Ayush No because dups is a set, so the lookup is O(1). If dups was a list you would be correct.

Comment: Ah, so that was what I was missing. Thanks

Comment: @Ayush At https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity they state that the "average case" is O(1) although a "worst case" set lookup is O(n). I assume that that is for a pathologically bad case with lots of hash collisions. Interestingly, the Wikipedia discussion of "pathological" references precisely this example - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_(mathematics)#Computer_science

Comment: Right, though I believe all of that has nothing to do with sets itself, and can be said for hashing in general, yes?

Comment: @Ayush Yes I believe the same would apply to dictionaries for example.